# NPSP trigger npe01.IndividualAccounts failing in sandbox

Tags: sandbox, customsetting, nonprofit-starter-pack

> NPSP trigger npe01.IndividualAccounts failing with the following
>   error: Apex trigger npe01.IndividualAccounts caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator: npe01.IndividualAccounts:
>   execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert
>   failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE,
>   duplicate value found: SetupOwnerId duplicates value on record with
>   id: 00DZ0000001De5X: []: (npe01)

Note - this is the first refresh I have done since Winter 14 upgrade

Can anyone tell me how I might get a hold of someone who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with a scheduled fix forthcoming (safe harbor). You can follow the issue here:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0qwAAC

To resolve the issue, you will need to either wait until the patch is released and refresh your sandbox or create a case with Salesforce support.

EDIT: This issue is also being discussed here:
[Unable to insert new records into "hierarchy" type Custom Setting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/unable-to-insert-new-records-into-hierarchy-type-custom-setting)

Comment: two questions: 1) so, is this an issue with the NPSP or SalesForce? 2) Can you direct me to a site that will give me instructions on how to fix the custom settings?

Comment: It is an issue with Salesforce. Hopefully my instructions above are clear enough but if not, here is a help article about creating custom settings: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_define.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Actually, I tried to uninstall contacts & organizations, but it wouldn't let me.  I have a ticket open with Salesforce support, but thought I might get a magic bullet from this team.

Comment: I've updated the link to the Known Issue and instructions for resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I received another note directing me to the following Known Issue in Salesforce:
Winter 14 - Error on custom settings "duplicate value found: SetupOwnerId"

Sandbox

Last updated Today ·Reference W-1890544 ·Reported By 1 users
SCHEDULED - WINTER '14 PATCH 10.0

Summary
Some customers have observed that after they have refreshed a sandbox they are unable to make an org-wide row in any of the custom settings tables. Error "duplicate value found: SetupOwnerId duplicates value on record with id: 00DK000000XXXXX"

Repro
In Setup > Develop > Custom Settings > "Custom Setting" Click New for the Default Organization Level Value settings and Save

Workaround
-Reach out to support by creating a case requesting to run a script in order to clear the inconsistencies within the meta data. 
-Refresh the sandbox POST fix (i.e, once the fix has been deployed to your CSx instance), this should resolve the issue too